# Load entire text file in database using python

Tags: python, database, load, netezza, operation

I want to load entire text file having two fields separated by delimiter `||` into my netezza database.
    Inserting each n every row degrades my performance since the data set is huge.

My text file is like:

```
ING BANK, N.V.||520639
STANDARD CHARTERED BANK MALAYSIA BERHAD||483551
VJA||492287
```

Could you please help in suggesting how can I upload my file in database in a single go?

Thanks.

Comment: I tried using LOAD DATA INFILE but an error is been thrown.Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#74>", line 1, in <module>
    curs.execute(sql)
ProgrammingError: ('42000', '[42000] ERROR:  \'LOAD DATA INFILE \'bankdata.TXT\'\n                           INTO TABLE INS_EDW_QA.dbo.BNK_CDE_TEST\n                           FIELDS TERMINATED BY \'||\'\n                           LINES TERMINATED BY \'\n\'\'\nerror         ^ found "DATA" (at char 6) expecting `SCONST\' (27) (SQLExecDirectW)')

Comment: Could you please suggest what is wrong here or suggest some other method to load the file at a single go?

Comment: You appear to be using MySQL load syntax, but as I understand it you are trying to load data into Netezza instead?  Are you running a python script locally on the Netezza server, or are you running it remotely with an ODBC connection?

Comment: I am connected to netezza with pyodbc. Connection is made with this code, conn = pyodbc.connect(dsn='NZSQL'). I am running python 2.7 on my local.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are loading the data to Netezza remotely via an ODBC connection, you can use the following statement as a template. In it, I load from a text file local to my windows workstation using an ODBC connection through a generic SQL development tool.

```
INSERT INTO BNK_CDE_TEST
SELECT *
FROM external 'c:\bankdata.TXT'
USING (DELIMITER '|' REMOTESOURCE 'ODBC');
```

It is important to note that Netezza does not support multiple-character column delimiters.  You either need to pre-process your data to convert your '||' delimiter to something else, or you need to perform a trick like the following where we use '|' as the delimiter so that '||' is treated as two delimiters around a junk empty column.

```
INSERT INTO BNK_CDE_TEST
SELECT COL1,   COL2
FROM external 'c:\bankdata.TXT' (COL1 VARCHAR(100), junkcol INT, col2 bigint)
USING (DELIMITER '|' REMOTESOURCE 'ODBC');
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Information is really helpful. I changed my delimiter to '|' and tried running the first command. I got this error: Error: ('HY000', '[HY000] Error occured while opening data file (38) (SQLExecDirectW)').  Please suggest what is wrong here.

Comment: This indicates that the path following "FROM EXTERNAL..." is not correct in some way.  Looking at your comment above, it looks like you are perhaps using a relative path. Loading in this fashion will require a full path specification.  Also, the first example I give probably won't work for your particular case because of the double delimiter '||'.  For your testing I'd say try the second one in the answer with the full path.